# ConTeXt: Matrix inside startalign/stopalign changes specified column alignment

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, matrices, context

Example:

```
\starttext
\startformula
    \startalign[n=2,align={right,left}]
        \NC x
        \NC = a ~ long ~ sequence ~ of ~ terms
        \NR
        \NC y
        \NC = ok ~ left
        \NR
        \NC \startmatrix[left={\left\lbrack},right={\right\rbrack}]
                \NC x \NR
                \NC y \NR
            \stopmatrix
        \NC = why ~ right?
        \NR
        \NC y
        \NC = ok ~ left ~ again
        \NR
    \stopalign
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

After the matrix, the specified alignment from `\startalign` is not applied any more:

[image: Screenshot of the resulting pdf of the example]

I thought it was related to https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2017/089631.html but the code snippet from there did not fix the issue for me.

Using

```
 \NC \omit $\displaystyle ...$ \hfill
```

I can push the content in the misaligned row to the left, but the spacing around the equal sign is not quite right then. Is there a better solution (ideally one that fixes the problem document-wide)?

Version: `2019.03.21 21:39`

Comment: Workaround: Add another column and you get the equal signs aligned

Comment: That is interesting. I've tested a couple of column configurations and I think I know what happens now: when a matrix is placed in a cell of the align block, it resets the alignment properties for that row. So e.g. if the alignment is {right,left,middle} and a matrix is placed in column 1, the alignment of column 2 starts at right again instead of continuing with left and column 3 is left-aligned instead of centered.

Comment: Looks like a candidate for the context mailing list

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug. Please report on the context mailing list.

Comment: Here is the link to the corresponding mailing list thread: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2019/094457.html. Thank you Aditya for posting, I hadn't had the time in the last few days.

Comment: @chpolste The bug has been fixed in the latest beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in the math matrix code that was introduced when trying to fix a previous limitation (nested matrices did not inherit distance key). It has been fixed in the [latest beta (2018.04.04)](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/commit/64f6e8fc0c6cb9254a6fe3db0b4ab31c51cf8524).

For completeness, here is the output corresponding to the MWE in the question:

```
\starttext
\startformula
    \startalign[n=2,align={right,left}]
        \NC x
        \NC = a ~ long ~ sequence ~ of ~ terms
        \NR
        \NC y
        \NC = ok ~ left
        \NR
        \NC \startmatrix[left={\left\lbrack},right={\right\rbrack}]
                \NC x \NR
                \NC y \NR
            \stopmatrix
        \NC = why ~ right?
        \NR
        \NC y
        \NC = ok ~ left ~ again
        \NR
    \stopalign
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your issue looks like a bug. Here is a workaround using three columns instead of two:

```
\starttext

\def\xymatrix{ \startmatrix[left={\left\lbrack},right={\right\rbrack}] \NC x \NR \NC y \NR \stopmatrix }

\startformula
    \startalign[n=3,align={right,left,left}]
        \NC \NC x               \NC = a ~ long ~ sequence ~ of ~ terms    \NR
        \NC \NC y               \NC = ok ~ left                           \NR
        \NC \xymatrix       \NC \NC = why ~ right?                        \NR
        \NC \NC y               \NC = ok ~ left ~ again                   \NR
    \stopalign
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

[image]